# Why is the contact form not working in my site?

Tags: php, forms, html, contacts

The contact form doesnt work

Here is the code im using in the page.

## Jquery in Index.html

```
<!--contact form -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){
        
        //stop the form from being submitted
        e.preventDefault();
        
        /* declare the variables, var error is the variable that we use on the end
        to determine if there was an error or not */
        var error = false;
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        
        /* in the next section we do the checking by using VARIABLE.length
        where VARIABLE is the variable we are checking (like name, email),
        length is a javascript function to get the number of characters.
        And as you can see if the num of characters is 0 we set the error
        variable to true and show the name_error div with the fadeIn effect. 
        if it's not 0 then we fadeOut the div( that's if the div is shown and
        the error is fixed it fadesOut. 
        
        The only difference from these checks is the email checking, we have
        email.indexOf('@') which checks if there is @ in the email input field.
        This javascript function will return -1 if no occurence have been found.*/
        if(name.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
            var error = true;
            $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
       
        if(message.length == 0){
            var error = true;
            $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
        }
        
        //now when the validation is done we check if the error variable is false (no errors)
        if(error == false){
            //disable the submit button to avoid spamming
            //and change the button text to Sending...
            $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });
            
            /* using the jquery's post(ajax) function and a lifesaver
            function serialize() which gets all the data from the form
            we submit it to send_email.php */
            $.post("send_email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                //and after the ajax request ends we check the text returned
                if(result == 'sent'){
                    //if the mail is sent remove the submit paragraph
                     $('#cf_submit_p').remove();
                    //and show the mail success div with fadeIn
                    $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                }else{
                    //show the mail failed div
                    $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                    //reenable the submit button by removing attribute disabled and change the text back to Send The Message
                    $('#send_message').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send The Message');
                }
            });
        }
    });    
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML Code for the Container

## Contact-Form in HTML @ index.html

```
<!--contact form -->
<div id="contact-form">
<div id="contact_form_holder">
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="contact_form">

<p>
Your Name:
  <input name="name" class="field" id="name" type="text">
</p><div id="name_error" class="error"><img src="web_files/error.png">&nbsp;Please enter your name</div>
<p></p>

<p>
Your Email:
</p><div><input name="email" class="field" id="email" type="text">
<div id="email_error" class="error"><img src="web_files/error.png">&nbsp;OOps!! i can't get back to you in this mail id</div>
</div>
<p></p>

<p>
The Message:
</p><div>
<textarea name="message" class="field" id="message"></textarea>
<div id="message_error" class="error"><img src="web_files/error.png"> Forgot why you came here?</div></div>

<p></p>

<div id="mail_success" class="success"><img src="web_files/success.png"> Thank you. The mailman is on his way.</div>
<div id="mail_fail" class="error"><img src="web_files/error.png"> Sorry, don't know what happened. Try later.</div>
<p id="cf_submit_p">
<!--<input type='submit' id='send_message' value='Send it to me' class="submit"> -->
<input id="send_message" value="Send The Message" class="submit" type="submit">
</p>


</form>  
</div>
</div> 

<!--contact form -->
```

And at last here is the PHP code as

## send_email.php

```
 //we need to get our variables first  

$email_to =   'mail@mail.com'<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l=document.getElementById("__cf_email__");        a=l.className;if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2)    {c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);    l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})(); 
/* ]]> */ 
</script>';     
//the address to which the email will be sent  
    $name     =   $_POST['name'];  
    $email    =   $_POST['email'];  
    $message  =   $_POST['message'];  

    /*the $header variable is for the additional headers in the mail function, 
 we are asigning 2 values, first one is FROM and the second one is REPLY-TO. 
 That way when we want to reply the email gmail(or yahoo or hotmail...) will know 
 who are we replying to. */  
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";  
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";  

if(mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $headers)){  
    echo 'sent'; // we are sending this text to the ajax request telling it that the mail is sent..  
}else{  
    echo 'failed';// ... or this one to tell it that it wasn't sent  
    }
```

Comment: What in the world is this ? What is JS doing in PHP ?

Comment: no ! i tried reoving js it didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Your error is at your first line in your PHP-code:

```
$email_to = 'email@email.com'<script type="text/javascript">
```

Your string ends after the e-mail address. Correct it to

```
$email_to = 'email@email.com';
```

and you should be fine.

Also, what is the JavaScript doing inside the PHP? Remove it or make sure to either echo it, or place it outside of your PHP-tags.

Answer (score 0):

1)Change the first line of your php code to

`$email_to = 'some.person@example.com';`

2)Remove the JavaScript from the PHP file.

If its still not working, change all the `$_POST` to `$_GET` and enter the values of the variables yourself. Then run the code and tell me the output.

*EDIT* :

I have found your error. You have not opened your php file correctly.
http://www.justyesh.in/send_email.php

You begin PHP with `<?php` and close it with `?>`